# How can I prove that $ f(x) = \sin (\ln(x))$ doesn't admit a limit?

Tags: real-analysis

I have two sequences such that : $U_n = e^{- 2n\pi}$ and $V_n =e^{-2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}}$.

$f(U_n) = -\sin(2n\pi)$ and $f(V_n) = \cos(2n\pi)$

Also we have: $\lim U_n = \lim V_n = 0$

I don't know how to show that  $ f$ doesn't admit a limit at $ x = 0 $ and on $+ \infty$

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't have a limit where?

Comment: @Adel On $ x = 0 $ and on $+ \infty $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $a_n=e^n $ then  $a_n\to\infty $ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin (\ln e^n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin n$ doesn't exist.

Take $a_n=e^{-n} $ then  $a_n\to 0 $ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin (\ln e^{-n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(- n)$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

*Hints:*

- If $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=L$ exists, then for every sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n\to 0$ it holds $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=L$.
- $\lim_{n\to-\infty}V_n=\lim_{n\to-\infty}U_n=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}V_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}U_n=0$.
- $f(U_n)=0$ and $f(V_n)=1$ for every $n$.